# Google+ buttons policy violation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, google-plus

I wonder if Stack Overflow use of Google+ is against Google+ [button policy](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/buttons-policy):

> For buttons that may be rendered by the Publisher, such as the Sharing
>   link, the Publisher must use only the official Google-provided icon or
>   a plain text and link combination.

The Google+ share icon used on Stack Overflow is not a Google-provided one.

I'm going to do something similar on my site, but I need to make sure it is legal.

Comment: It's not a question of legality, but of contract/license violatoin.

Comment: This seems to be one of those things that no one cares about honestly...I've seen untold dozens of sites custom style facebook, Twitter and G+ icons. I'm not saying it's right from an IP/contract perspective, but...it's only sensible.

Comment: If you're looking for a legal answer for something you're contemplating doing on your own site, this is not the right place.

Comment: Closed awaiting clarification - we can probably explain how/why we implement these links, but can't give you legal advice.